# SpriteKit + iOS8. What is the orientation of the electric field SKFieldNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to wrap my head around the orientation of the electric force field SKFieldNode of SpriteKit.

Here is an example:
1) Create an electric field with a circular region and place it a x, y.
2) Create a square SkSpriteNode that fits within the electric field region and position the sprite at the same x, y as the field node position.

Will the electric field now act as a circular containment force field preventing the sprites movement if it is subjected to an impulse force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/electricField):

> The force points toward the field node’s position and has a magnitude proportional to the field’s `strength` property and the physics body’s `charge` property.

The field will not prevent anything, it will apply its own force to physics bodies subjected to the field based on the strength and charge properties *on top of* any other forces/fields acting on the body. Forces (impulses) are always accumulative, meaning they can even cancel each other out if there are two identical but directly opposing forces applied to the same body.

Comment: LearnCocos2D, my question is what is the direction and distribution of force vectors. Can you confirm that the vector origins distributed along the the ring whose radius is the region radius and that the  direction of these vectors is towards the origin? So all vectors are "focused" on the region origin. Yes, I get that this will not constrain what they point at.

Comment: The direction is as the documentation states. I don't know what you mean by distribution. As long as a node is affected by a field node, the field node will apply an impulse to the node's body in the direction of the field node's position.

Comment: Ah, I see. So just a single vector with Lorentz falloff behavior. Got it. Thanks for the clarification.